# Start and Stop AWS RDS's with Ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-rds

I want to schedule a stop and start for an RDS with an Ansible playbook but I do not see the command in the rds module or rds_instance. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the information here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

May not be native to Ansible, but you can always initiate the AWS CLi command via Ansible to get it done.